# Subtracting from xml file from the "quantity"node

Tags: c#, xml

I have a WinForm C# application that allows waiters to take customer orders from a restaurant. Currently from the image below you can see a datagridview outputting the menu.xml file. Once the waiter chooses a meal and a seat, that information is passed onto a new xml file titled order.xml. I have got all of this to work perfectly.

What I need help in is how can I get the program to subtract the stock once the order has been submitted. For example the current quantity is 12, Once I select Meal 1 (Fish and Chips) and click submit, I want the menu.xml file to be updated to show the quantity as 11. Could somebody please help as to how I would do this.

Cheers.

Sample of my menu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MenuInfo>
<Meal>
<MealID>1</MealID>
<Food>Meal 1 (Fish and Chips)</Food>
<Price>£4.99</Price>
<Time>25 minutes</Time>
<Quantity>12</Quantity>
</Meal>
<Meal>
<MealID>2</MealID>
<Food>Meal 2 (Chicken and Chips)</Food>
<Price>£3.99</Price>
<Time>25 minutes</Time>
<Quantity>12</Quantity>
</Meal>
<Meal>
<MealID>3</MealID>
<Food>Meal 3 (Saussage and Chips)</Food>
<Price>£2.99</Price>
<Time>25 minutes</Time>
<Quantity>12</Quantity>
</Meal>
<Meal>
<MealID>4</MealID>
<Food>Meal 4 (Burger and Chips)</Food>
<Price>£5.99</Price>
<Time>25 minutes</Time>
<Quantity>12</Quantity>
</Meal>
</MenuInfo>
```

[Image of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neQMb.jpg)

******UPDATE******

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("order.xml");
        XElement root = new XElement("MenuInfo");

        foreach(DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if(dr.Selected)
            {
                root.Add(new XElement("Meal", dr.Cells["Food"].Value.ToString()));
                root.Add(new XElement("SeatID", _seat));
                root.Add(new XElement("TableID", buttonTable1.Text));
                root.Add(new XElement("Price", dr.Cells["Price"].Value.ToString()));
                doc.Element("Menu").Add(root);
                doc.Save("order.xml");
            }
        }
```

This is my code for when the user submits an order into the "order.xml" file. Sorry for the confusion. This is all based on Linq to XML

Comment: There is an example in XmlDocument class that do the job. Search for Navigate the document tree - Get child nodes   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the below code - hope this is what you want:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(@"<MenuInfo>
                            <Meal>
                            <MealID>1</MealID>
                            <Food>Meal 1 (Fish and Chips)</Food>
                            <Price>£4.99</Price>
                            <Time>25 minutes</Time>
                            <Quantity>12</Quantity>
                            </Meal>
                        </MenuInfo>");
        XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/MenuInfo/Meal/Quantity");            
        int qty = Convert.ToInt32(node.InnerText);

         // Deducting 1 from orginal quantity, you can use variable instead of quantity 1
        node.InnerText = (qty - 1).ToString();

        //Finally you can retrieve modified xml from using doc.InnerXml
        string modifiedXml = doc.InnerXml
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the menu contains more than one meal, right ? :)

Comment: I hope you'll believe that a Meal has only a MealID but a MenuInfo will have many Meal and getting single node with '/MenuInfo/Meal/Quantity' will return the quantity of first meal. That is a sample only how to change value of a node (here used - quantity node). Thanks @Ted

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using `XmlDocument` you can do the following:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

xml.LoadXml(@"
    <MenuInfo>
        <Meal>
            <MealID>1</MealID>
            <Food>Meal 1 (Fish and Chips)</Food>
            <Price>£4.99</Price>
            <Time>25 minutes</Time>
            <Quantity>12</Quantity>
        </Meal>
    </MenuInfo>");

// this selects the correct MealID and updates the quantity all in one go
xml.SelectSingleNode("/MenuInfo/Meal[MealID = '1']/Quantity").InnerText = "11";
```

Comment: So, I am actually using Linq to XML (sorry I did not mention that). Also the menu.xml file is external and is being loaded by linq to xml which also contains four different meals. If I am correct the code sampple you provided will only work for Meal with the ID 1?

Comment: That's right. Regardless of how the xmldoc was loaded, the above will work. (If there are more levels above MenuInfo, add them to the xpath)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but why would you load one part of the xml as you did above? What about the remainder of the xml document. There are 4 different meals and the code you sampled will only work with Meal 1. Also I used XDocument to load the xml file, so "xml.SelectSingleNode" is not recognised, what would I use to replace that?

Comment: I have managed to change the code so that it would work with Linq to Xml, the code is below

doc.XPathSelectElement("/MenuInfo/Meal[MealID = '1']/Quantity").Value = "11";

However now I am getting this error when I run the code, do you have an idea on how to fix this?

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I only loaded the XML that you've shared. Share the complete XML and I'll update the code with the correct xpath query

Comment: How would I get the code to recognise which meal to subtract from based on what the user chooses?

Comment: Are you serious? Ever heard of variables?

Comment: I am a beginner in C# so I don't know how to work with this language.